# Use a different confirmation url on completed webform submission in email confirmation link

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

When a user submits a webform submission, they get redirected to a confirmation page, in my case its node/40. Now if they also have to click on an email confirmation link, it also sends them to the same confirmation url node/40.

How can you set a different confirmation url for the one in the email?

[image]

Comment: How's the e-mail confirmation link being sent? custom module? or...

Comment: Its being sent via the webform **Confirmation request emails (always send)** page. This page: http://prntscr.com/gsyno2

Comment: nevermind! i found it... there's another field for another url on that page. didn't see it.

Comment: @duckx If you found the answer, please write a brief answer so that it's clear your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a **Set the redirect URL** field in the "confirmation" email page setting which i totally missed. See below:

[image]